# LINQ Group by - linq to entities does not recognize the method 'char get_chars(int32) method

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing this LINQ to group product name by letter but hit this error: linq to entities does not recognize the method 'char get_chars(int32) method

```
var output = (from p in db.Products
              group p by p.ProductName[0]);

foreach (var prod in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prod.Key);
    // second foreach loop later.
}
```

The database I used is Microsoft Northwind sample database. I am using EDMX. In db, datatype for `ProductName` is `nvarchar` while in the `Product` class, `ProductName` is `string` datatype.

If I changed my code to below, I can all the letter printed out.

```
var output = (from p in db.Products
              group p by p.ProductName);

foreach (var prod in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prod.Key[0]);
    // second foreach loop later.
}
```

Comment: Try `group p by p.ProductName.Substring(0, 1)`

Comment: oh, that's it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate the char indexer into valid SQL. Instead you can use `string.Substring`, for example:

```
var output = (from p in db.Products
              group p by p.ProductName.Substring(0, 1));
```

Comment: This will lead to an exception if your ProductName is empty

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse No it won't. This is Entity Framework meaning this gets translated to an SQL query which uses the SQL `SUBSTRING` function and will return a `null` not an exception.